# Prevent bash from interpreting without quoting everything

Tags: bash

I need to output some text as bash script, but in a script. I use cat for this, but it has one drawback. It **interprets variables and stuff** during it is being written. I do want to **prevent this**.

How to do that **without quoting all varibles** (my script is failrly long)? Example

```
cat >/tmp/script << EOF
  $HOSTNAME
  # lots of other stuff I do NOT want to escape like \$VARIABLE
  # ...
EOF

cat /tmp/script
myhostname.mylan
```

I want:

```
cat /tmp/script
$HOSTNAME
```

Edit: Please note my script (here only *$HOSTNAME*) is very long, I dont want to change it all. Also **single quoting does not work** with <<

```
cat >/tmp/script '<< EOF
  $HOSTNAME
EOF'
File not found: EOF'
```

What's the trick? Thanks.

Comment: Could someone tell why it's not interpreted in my case? `$ echo $HOSTNAME` -> `myhost`; `$ echo \$HOSTNAME` -> `$HOSTNAME`; `$ echo \$HOSTNAME > /tmp/s; cat /tmp/s` -> `$HOSTNAME`

Answer (score 106, accepted):

If you want everything quoted:

```
cat << 'EOF'
stuff here with $signs is OK
as are `backquotes`
EOF
```

See the section on "here documents" in the manual.

Comment: `cat << EOF` does'nt escape `$` things and `cat << 'EOF'` does, good catch here!

Comment: AMAZING!
I only wish I would have beed able to grant move up votes :-)

Answer (score 2):

Escape the $:

```
cat >/tmp/script << EOF
  \$HOSTNAME
EOF
```

Comment: No, as described - I have thousands lines of it - I am not going to do that. This would work in my simple example, yes, but I am trying to find a different solution. Thats why the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Use sed:

```
 sed -n '20,30p' "$0"
```

to print line 20 to 30, SSCE:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat >/dev/null << EOF
 3
 4 $HOSTNAME
 5 ls 
 6 $(ls -l) 
 7
 8 echo 'foo
 9 bar' 
 10
 11 echo "Foo
 12 $((4+4)) Bar" 
EOF
sed -n '3,12p' "$0"
echo "fine?"
```

working with head/tail should work too.

You will have to adjust the numbers, if you work on it and insert or delete lines.

Comment: Upvoting, there is a solution now, but nice effort! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**To escape $ as not a variable you can do it like this**

> Example

Suppose I want to write **$http_upgrade** but in bash $ will consider as variable and it will show me an error to resolve this
we use like

**'$http_upgrade'**

```
cat >/tmp/script << EOF
     proxy_cache_bypass '\$http_upgrade';
EOF
```

You can use like